# Get list of tables and stored procedures created in past one month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

> I want to do find names of tables and stored procedures that were created
>   in past month

I searched in several places but I didn't get any proper solution.
To be more clear on requirement I need a query which can return me a list of tables which were created in past month in my database.

Comment: Please add more information, this is quite unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEDIFF(D,create_date, GETDATE()) < 7
```

May be this could work for u

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the view [`sys.objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    CASE type WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table' WHEN 'P' THEN 'SP' END AS type, 
    name, 
    create_date 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE 
    type IN ('U', 'P') AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, create_date, GETDATE()) < 1
```

Comment: @Rushabhpatel create_date *is* create date of object. Do not drop and re-create, use `alter` or else you get the wrong date.

Comment: yA i did so but its that i am changing database and i have already some tables and data on new database